# Router Outlet in Layout

Tags: angular

I would like to change the layout in my Angular 2 app. The layout surrounds the router-outler, and there is my problem. So i can't do something like :

```
<router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
```

My default outlet must be between some tags of the layout...
To illustrate what i want, i tried this transclusion :

```
<router-outlet name="layout">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

And in my layout, I have a `<ng-content></ng-content>`. But transclusion doesn't seem to work with outlets.

How could I make somehting similar to a layout in Angular 2?
Thank you !

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what the actual problem is you try to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The component added to a router outlet by the router is added below the  `<router-outlet>`, therefore adding something inside the `<router-outlet>` is pointless and it also is not supported.

The "inner" `<router-outlet>` needs to be added into the component, that is added to `<router-outlet>` by the router.